# Is it possible to perform clustering analysis in an object features matrix?

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis

I'm currently trying to study different clustering analysis methods however in the examples I'm looking at I can only find clustering analysis on matrix with numerical variables. I was wondering if I could apply some of the most known clustering methods such as K-clustering or Hierarchical clustering on a matrix containing non numerical values. For example:

[image: example matrix]

How would one person perform clustering analysis on this kind of matrix?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

Just use an appropriate distance measure for your data and you can use HAC.

Or choose another algorithm. There are *dozens* of clustering algorithms, not just two.

The main problem with such data is that the results are mostly meaningless. By what notion of significance could a result be better than random on this data?